# Pentaho MySQL Repository connection error (conn:4584)

Tags: mysql, pentaho-data-integration

I configured Carte Server V.8.1 to enable automated task scheduler in dedicated server. This Carte is connected to MariaDB Repository and its experiencing Conection Socket Error after getting the server up for more than 24 hours.

Someone know if there is any file where i can config MySQL Timeout for MariaDB in JDBC?

PDI.log file is the following:

```
2018-10-04 08:01:02.569 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting entry [EXTRAE SEMANA CAMBIOS]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.685 INFO  <Thread-906> []  exec(1, 0, EXTRAE SEMANA CAMBIOS.0)
2018-10-04 08:01:02.685 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting job entry
2018-10-04 08:01:02.685 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Opening transformation: [null] in directory [/CONTROL CAMBIOS]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.686 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Loading transformation from repository [EXTRAE SEMANA CAMBIOS] in directory [/CONTROL CAMBIOS]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.725 ERROR <Thread-906> []  Unable to run job CONTROL CAMBIOS. The EXTRAE SEMANA CAMBIOS has an error. An error occured loading the directory tree from the repository

ERROR executing query
(conn:4584) Could not send query: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
2018-10-04 08:01:02.726 ERROR <Thread-906> []  org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
An error occured loading the directory tree from the repository

ERROR executing query
(conn:4584) Could not send query: Connection reset by peer: socket write error


    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.loadRepositoryDirectoryTree(KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.java:108)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.loadRepositoryDirectoryTree(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:608)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.findDirectory(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:620)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.getTransMeta(JobEntryTrans.java:1324)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.execute(JobEntryTrans.java:704)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:676)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:817)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:493)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:380)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
ERROR executing query
(conn:4584) Could not send query: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1823)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate$6.call(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1599)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate$6.call(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1597)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.callRead(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1992)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.getIDs(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1597)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.getSubDirectoryIDs(KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.java:290)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.getSubDirectoryIDs(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:684)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.loadRepositoryDirectoryTree(KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.java:98)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn:4584) Could not send query: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:156)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:118)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:250)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1811)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not send query: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1726)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:223)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:218)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.output.StandardPacketOutputStream.flushBuffer(StandardPacketOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.output.AbstractPacketOutputStream.flush(AbstractPacketOutputStream.java:175)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:216)
    ... 22 more

2018-10-04 08:01:02.727 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting entry [INFORME CAMBIOS EXTRAE MAQUINAS DESCRIPCION]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.727 INFO  <Thread-906> []  exec(2, 0, INFORME CAMBIOS EXTRAE MAQUINAS DESCRIPCION.0)
2018-10-04 08:01:02.727 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting job entry
2018-10-04 08:01:02.727 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Opening transformation: [null] in directory [/CONTROL CAMBIOS]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.727 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Loading transformation from repository [INFORME CAMBIOS EXTRAE MAQUINAS DESCRIPCION] in directory [/CONTROL CAMBIOS]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.728 ERROR <Thread-906> []  Unable to run job CONTROL CAMBIOS. The INFORME CAMBIOS EXTRAE MAQUINAS DESCRIPCION has an error. An error occured loading the directory tree from the repository

ERROR executing query
execute() is called on closed statement
2018-10-04 08:01:02.728 ERROR <Thread-906> []  org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
An error occured loading the directory tree from the repository

ERROR executing query
execute() is called on closed statement


    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.loadRepositoryDirectoryTree(KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.java:108)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.loadRepositoryDirectoryTree(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:608)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.findDirectory(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:620)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.getTransMeta(JobEntryTrans.java:1324)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.execute(JobEntryTrans.java:704)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:676)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:817)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:817)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:493)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:380)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
ERROR executing query
execute() is called on closed statement

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1823)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate$6.call(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1599)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate$6.call(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1597)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.callRead(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1992)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.getIDs(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:1597)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.getSubDirectoryIDs(KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.java:290)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.getSubDirectoryIDs(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:684)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.loadRepositoryDirectoryTree(KettleDatabaseRepositoryDirectoryDelegate.java:98)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: execute() is called on closed statement
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQueryPrologue(MariaDbStatement.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:211)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1811)
    ... 16 more

2018-10-04 08:01:02.729 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting entry [COPIAR FICHEROS A REMOTO]
2018-10-04 08:01:02.729 INFO  <Thread-906> []  exec(3, 0, COPIAR FICHEROS A REMOTO.0)
2018-10-04 08:01:02.729 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting job entry
2018-10-04 08:01:02.730 ERROR <Thread-906> []  We can not find folder [\\tsclient\C\InformesSpoon\CAMBIOS\] !
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 ERROR <Thread-906> []  We can not create folder [\\tsclient\C\InformesSpoon\CAMBIOS\]. Exception : org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not create folder "file:////tsclient/C/". 
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Finished job entry [COPIAR FICHEROS A REMOTO] (result=[false])
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Finished job entry [INFORME CAMBIOS EXTRAE MAQUINAS DESCRIPCION] (result=[false])
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Finished job entry [EXTRAE SEMANA CAMBIOS] (result=[false])
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 INFO  <Thread-906> []  exec(0, 0, START.0)
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 INFO  <Thread-906> []  Starting job entry
2018-10-04 08:01:02.732 INFO  <Thread-906> []  CONTROL CAMBIOS
2018-10-04 10:14:43.171 WARN  <Thread-906> []  Job execution finished
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the error is because the name of the folder has spaces or even the trans/job name has spaces too. Using Spoon and connected to your repo, rename with no spaces your trans/job and move to another folder with no spaces.